# Should I be carrying my checked-in baggage while shifting flights be it domestic or international?

Tags: air-travel, transit, lhr, ord, check-in

I have booked a flight with British Airways (BA):

1. Hyderabad to London (BA).
2. London to Chicago (BA operated by American Airlines -> International Flight).
3. Chicago to Cincinnati (BA operated by American Airlines -> Domestic Flight).

Should I transfer my luggage between flights be it domestic or international?

Comment: The answers are accurate but, if you have any doubts, you can always confirm with the check-in agent at Hyderabad.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are on a single itinerary (given that you have mentioned codeshare flights), your luggage will be tagged to your final destination, Cincinnati.

What this means in practice is that you will not need to collect and recheck your luggage in London. However, you will need to collect it and recheck in Chicago.

When you first arrive in the US, you will be required to clear customs.  This requires you to walk through the declaration lane with all of your luggage.

Immediately following immigration to the US, collect your luggage from the belt, walk through customs, then after customs, you will find a desk where you can onward check your luggage for the final leg of your flight.

Comment: Technically speaking, he won't actually need to re-check his luggage in Chicago; he'll just need to drop it back off at the airline information desk after customs. As you mentioned, it will already be checked to Cincinnati. No need to re-check.

Answer (score 3):

As @PassKit said previously. Here's the [specific instructions](http://www.flychicago.com/OHare/EN/AtAirport/Facilities/TravelerServices/International-Traveler.aspx) for Chicago O'Hare

> **CONNECTING FLIGHTS**
>
> If you have a connecting flight and are checked through all the way to
>   your destination, once you claim your luggage and pass through Customs
>   you can drop it off at the airline information desks located directly
>   after Customs.
>
> If you are not checked all the way through to your final destination
>   and are flying with either United or American Airlines on your
>   connecting flight, there are airline employees in Terminal 5 ready to
>   re-check your luggage for you. You will not have to take your luggage
>   with you to the domestic terminals.